# Validate one element inside an ng-repeat only when dirty

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form with simple `ng-required` validation. This works for simple input fields but I don't know what to do with an array inside an ng-repeat. I want the inputs inside the ng-repeat to become invalid only after they lose focus once.

Here is an example of the problem:

https://jsbin.com/kugobiwoxo/1/edit?html,js,output

This works: `ng-required="myform.MyName.$touched"`

This doesn't: `ng-required="myform.contact[{{$index}}].$touched"`

Is there some other expression I can use in the second case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angularjs does not honor indexed input names or ids. In `ng-repeat` you need to use `ng-form` attribute.

The changes I made to your div containing `ng-repeat` are as follows

```
<div ng-repeat='contact in model.Contacts' ng-form="innerform">
      <label for='name'>Contact {{$index}}:</label>
      <input type='text' ng-model='contact.Name'
             id='name' name='contact'
             ng-required="innerform.contact.$touched" />

      <button ng-click='remove($event, $index)'>-</button>
    </div>
```

and it is working as desired as you can see in this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/cofejuvijo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: here is link to jsbin https://jsbin.com/cofejuvijo/1/edit?html,js,output, if I am using it correctly